# How do I go back to multi_user mode

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, multi-user, single-user

Here is my query:

```
IF EXISTS(%some query%)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY       

        ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET single_user WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

        --do something
        --throw some exception

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        --here I want to set database back to multi_user

        RAISERROR ('DBErrorMessage', @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
    END CATCH
END
```

What is the best way to set database back to `multi_user`? I am afraid that the most straightforward way might lead to an

> Database 'MyDatabase' is already open and can only have one user at a time.

exception.

By the most straightforward way I mean this one:

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET MULTI_USER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while, but I believe the `with rollback immediate` option is there to say you want this to succeed no matter what.  the normal behavior blocks until all running transactions have completed successfully.

Also, setting the database to multi-user mode when it's already multi-user is safe.

However, if you want to be really sure, use a nested try catch block.  The first one to handle any error moving to single user mode, and the inner one to handle errors that occur in single-user mode..

see [try-catch documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175976(v=sql.105).aspx)
and [alter database documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174269(v=sql.90).aspx)

A couple of final notes for completeness:

1) If the error is severe enough your connection will be closed, and your database will still be in single-user mode.

2) You should have a test instance where you can safely try this stuff out, so that you can learn what's going to happen in production.

Answer (score 1):

The "current user is currently connected to it" might be SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO window itself.

SELECT master database, and run

```
ALTER DATABASE TherapyDatabaseWTS
SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

Or if you want to do with SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO, then follow

```
Right click Database >> Properties >> Options >> State >> RestrictAccess 
                                                  >> Choose Multi_user and click OK
```

Comment: It could be the case sometimes, but what if I want to do that from my program?  
Is there any other way to achieve that?

Comment: my question is when SET SINGLE USER fails and throw exception, so database is already in multi-user state, why are you setting that

Comment: This is a deinstallation scenario. I want to set `[MyDatabase]` to `single_user`, then to drop db. And I want to set it back to `multi_user` in case of exception during the drop.

Comment: thats my point, first DB is multi-user, then you try to set as Single USer, but fails, so DB is automatically reamins in multi-user state? isn't

Comment: Not really. It is successfully set to single-user, then I try to drop db, fail to do so, db stays in single-user mode.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you simply put

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET MULTI_USER
```

after the CATCH ? It shouldn't find any active user since you are in single user from your program/stored procedure?

Also, have you tried putting everything in a transaction, using ROLLBACK in the CATCH block?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that db will be taken by my user? If it is guaranteed, then this variant suits me completely.

Comment: I thought that it is forbidden to have `ALTER DATABASE` inside of transaction in ms sql.

Comment: If you can set it to multi-user, then the currently logged user should be the only user in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a quick test:

```
BEGIN TRY       

    ALTER DATABASE DB1 SET SINGLE_USER
    SELECT 1/0 --it generates an error

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   ALTER DATABASE DB1 SET MULTI_USER 
END CATCH
```

It appears to be working, after the batch completes DB1 is still in Multi-User mode...

Answer (score 1):

1. Find out the user and the session id

- write a sql query as: sp_who (this will show all the processes)

2. Note down the “spid” of the user from the above query result and kill that session.
3. Change your db to multi-user mode

- enter the below query

  ALTER DATABASE [your db]

  SET MULTI_USER

Comment: Awesome. But how do you do step 2?